# Convexity of a function over a vectorial space

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

> Consider  $\mathcal{V}$ the set of vectors $X$ whose values $x_i$
>   are all positive.
>
> Then, consider the function f  : $\mathcal{V} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} ;
> > f(X)=\frac{\max_i(x_i)}{\min_j(x_j)}$
>
> What can be said of the convexity of f ?

I tried to perform the following strategy :

1) Show that on $]0,+\infty[^2$, $g(x,y)=\frac{x}{y}$ is convex

2) show that the pointwise max of a finite number of convex functions is convex

But, unfortunately, g is not convex. For instance :

$\frac{1}{2}(g(3,2)+g(1,1)) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2}+1)=1.25$

$g(\frac{3+1}{2},\frac{2+1}{2})=\frac{2}{1.5}=\frac{4}{3} >1.25$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, f is not convex. 
My counter-example for g was also a counter-example for f.

But, though f is not convex, you can prove that, on any line segment, the maximum of f is reached on one of the endpoints. (That's what I really needed actually).